# How can I pair a PlayStation 5 controller via bluetooth?

Tags: drivers, kernel, bluetooth, compiling, gamepad

I would like to use a PlayStation 5 controller (PlayStation DualSense) wirelessly.

If I connect it through a USB cable, it's recognized as a joystick device + audio card. But if I try to use it via bluetooth, it gets disconnected just after it's paired and connected.

I'm guessing it won't work without a proper driver. I read Sony [has released an official driver for PlayStation 5 controller](https://phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Sony-HID-PlayStation-PS5) which is [already integrated into the Linux Kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/hid/hid-playstation.c) since [Linux 5.12](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/HID_PLAYSTATION.html). Problem is, I have an older kernel version (4.4.0).

I tried to compile myself the driver using headers from the currently-installed version, but apparently it relies on files that don't exist yet (e.g. `linux/bits.h`). Besides, even if I copy the missing files, compilation still fails due to other errors.

So I was wondering:
¿Do I have to recompile the wole kernel to be able to use that driver? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

You are running an older version of Ubuntu that does not use the 5.x kernel. Upgrade the version of Ubuntu first. Try the controller and see if it works before going any further. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has a 5.x kernel.